# Event Timestamp Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics

I've got some events setup to report to Google Analytics, phone calls.  It works fine and reports what I have setup thus far.

```
<a onclick="window._gaq &amp;&amp; _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'MobileLinks', 'Phone', 'Our Facility Location']);" href="tel:5555555555">
```

I'd like to additionally like to report in GA the actual time (users local time)  that someone called using the link so I could tie this together with our phone system and scheduler to gauge appointment conversions.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks...  Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you migrating to [Google Analytics Universal](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) first (needs modifying your JS code).
Then you'll get access to [custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets), where you can store your custom parameters.

For user's local time you should create new [hit scope custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en) and pass the value from your website:

```
<a onclick="window.ga &amp;&amp; ga('send', 'event', 'MobileLinks', 'Phone', 'Our Facility Location', {'dimension1': new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60});" href="tel:5555555555">
```

You'll get a visitor's timezone.

Adding it to [ga:dateHour](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_datehour) + [ga:minute](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_minute) of the hit you will know his local time.